# Using analytics.js without react-ga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I want to integrate google analytics into my react app without using the react-ga package. Specifically, I would like to be able to access the `ga` function in a separate javascript script and possibly within a react component. How do I get access to the `ga` function in a separate javascript file if I import the analytics.js script into my html?

```js
console.log(ga.q)
```

```html
<script async src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `ga` is global, so have you tried *just* using it ?

Comment: Yes, you can see in the snippet that it says that `Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined`

Comment: use `global.ga` or `window.ga`. Both should work.

Answer (score 0):

ga and gtag (if you want to use it instead of ga, that I recommend it) are both accessible using window:

```
window.ga()

window.gtag()
```